# Разработка сайта на домене локально?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, сервер, веб-сервер, localhost

Постараюсь задать вопрос максимально понятно, так как не очень разбираюсь.

Верстая сайт на WordPress локально или на собственном хостинге, как правило, изначально создается сайт с доменом, который не будет использован впоследствии, например: "localhost", "service32874938.domain.com" и т.п.

Это создает неудобства при переносе, а конкретно "перепись ссылок". О способах переписать базу данных через mySQL консоль и массе плагинов мне, конечно, известно. Но иногда не все проходит гладко.

И поэтому, гораздо удобнее и приятнее было бы сразу на правильном домене делать. Возможно ли это локально или на VPS?

P.S. Как я понял, это умеет локальный сервер MAMP PRO, но хотелось бы немножко разобраться без дополнительных затрат и для собственного понимания и развития.

Спасибо за ответы заранее!

Comment: От перепеси ссылок избавиться элементарно - просто не пишите домен в ссылках

Comment: Локальная разработка - без затратная и наиболее удобная. Как сказали выше - пишите относительные пути, а не полные, это относится как к ссылкам на картинки, так и файлам. Создав базу, вы ее экспортируете и импортируете на хостинг без проблем. Нет смысла покупать хостинг, регистрировать домен, пока вы не разработаете сайт локально. Если хотите выпустить свою верстку в свет - https://github.io бесплатно. Когда пойдет код на серверных яп - выкупайте хостинг недорогой. До тех пор локалхост - ваше всё. Это ваша жила, даже можно сказать.

Comment: @andreymal как бы он ни писал, WordPress хранит абсолютные ссылки в базе.

Comment: Про перенос сайта на WordPress https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: На мой взгляд, самая удобная и быстрая система локальной разработки WordPress для Мака - это Flywheel: https://getflywheel.com/

Comment: @KAGGDesign "WordPress хранит абсолютные ссылки в базе" - вот и ещё одна причина избегать убогий вордпресс

Comment: @andreymal почитайте мой вопрос-ответ по ссылке, где дана ссылка на доводы, почему так. Я понимаю, что секту верующих в убогость WP вы не покинете, но расширить кругозор никогда не помешает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign почитал, и что? «it might be outside of the install» — повод хранить ещё более относительные ссылки, а путь к wordpress добавлять в шаблонизаторе/html-обработчике. «Any relative URLs also make it significantly more difficult to perform transformations when the install is moved» — бред, не имеющий отношения к реальности. «absolute URLs are needed in numerous other places» — тоже бред, а там, где абсолютные URL всё-таки нужны, шаблонизатор отлично справится со всем (и не надо мне тут пургу про баги гнать, вон у Django и Flask всё отлично с этим без багов, например).

Comment: (и да, этот комментарий должен был быть в чате, потому что не относится к сути вопроса)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете и локально использовать домен.

Пропишите ваш домен в `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` и сможете локально с ним работать. Все ссылки сохранятся при переносе:

```
127.0.0.1 ваш_домен.com
```

Тогда при открытии в браузере на этой машине адреса `ваш_домен.com` будет обращение к локальному серверу.

Comment: Да, супер, спасибо большое за подсказку это похоже на то, что я искал:)

Comment: @zz.skip рад помочь ^_^

Comment: а можно так же прописывать новые  ip и присваивать им адреса?  например 127.0.0.2 мой_домен.com или это противоестественно? =)

Comment: @zz.skip прописать можно любой ip. Только локальная машина - это `127.0.0.1`. Так-то можно и для `google.com` прописать ip того же яндекса, чтоб при вводе в браузере адреса гугла открывался яндекс.

Comment: копаю под mac os, там в файле hosts написано это "localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry." И это сбивает с толку. могу я править или лучше не трогать.

Comment: @zz.skip с маками никогда не работал. Не могу ничего посоветовать)

Comment: Везде можно прописывать любое количество доменов на адрес 127.0.0.1 Дальше их будет различать ваш локальный веб-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

- БД можно экспортировать с локального сервера и импортировать в
  удаленный.
- Сразу разрабатывать на VPS, как минимум небезопасно.
- Ссылки не должны быть привязаны к адресу, вместо `http://mysite.com/user` необходимо использовать просто `/user`

Comment: а как прописать конечный домен?

Comment: да относительные ссылки вещь полезная, но конкретно Wordpress не рекомендует этого делать и даже не предоставляет такой возможности в голом софте!

Comment: прописать куда? если хотите с ним работать на локальном сервере, то в файл hosts надо прописать `127.0.0.1 http://mysite.com`

Comment: Так вы сможете прописывать полные ссылки и разрабатывать на локальном сервере

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, уже рою в данном направлении, но Suvitruf был первее:)

Comment: @zz.skip, всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема при миграции даже не столько в домене, сколько в изменении путей. Имено поэтому "не всё гладко"

См подробнее [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562)